# Spring Data Project - Couchbase Integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, couchbase

I went over the below tutorials for using couchbase db via Spring

http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-couchbase/#quick-start

I see the below auto wiring in service class. UserRepository is an interface. I assume there should be an implementation which implements this interface and is exposed a bean. I don't see any class implementing this interface or being exposed as a bean. Is it possible to help in explaining how this works?

```
@Autowired
public MyService(UserRepository userRepository) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aim of the Spring-Data project is to create such implementations at runtime for you when you only define interfaces.

It will inspect the packages you configured for scan via reflection and discover `xxRepository` interfaces in them, at which point it will use a base class provided by the store-specific Spring Data subproject you chose (here Couchbase) to weave together a concrete implementation of `xxRepository` and inject it.

Comment: Thanks Simon! In this scenario UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String>. Does spring look at the base interface and weave the appropriate concrete implementation? All the examples that I saw extend CrudRepository. Is there any benefit in extending this or can it be used as it is?

Comment: The main benefit for extending is that you can define your own methods beyond save, delete, etc... Either with your own implementation or spring can derive some form of query out of some method names (lookup "query derivation")

Comment: Query derivation for couchbase is only part of spring data couchbase 2.0, currently in preview

Comment: Sure , I'll look it up.Thanks for your help Simon!

Comment: I'm reading your blog for details :) http://blog.couchbase.com/2015/august/spring-data-couchbase-2.0-preview